# Implementing a simple server / client concept in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, cross-platform

I'm searching for a library / framework / codesnippet that helps me build a really simple server / client. Both should be portable (linux/win/mac).

A picture says more then a thousand words so:
[image]

The server should be able to seperate diffrent clients.
What I'm looking for is only a hint on how to do the transfere. I've little experience with languages other then c++, and it was mostly plain easy to create a server that stores all the clients connected in an array and interacts with each one of them once you got pointed in the right direction.

What I looked into for C++ was RakNet and Boost.Asio.
I don't want to use RakNet because I might sell the application at some point (you never know) and Boost.Asio seems way to complex for me to understand and way to low-level.  All I really need is a simple send/recieve functionallity.
The json will be handled by me (I already looked into jsoncpp). One message will have a maximum length of 2048 bytes.

Any suggestions / hints / help on what to look into / what to use?
I'm really looking for something easy and not so much low-level to use as I don't need the low-level functionallity.

Thanks in advance,
Robin.

Comment: Although a picture with text doesn't say much more than those words.

Comment: No it isn't. I want to develop a small game with one of my friends (just for the purpose of learning stuff about opengl) and we though it would be cool if we could add network support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done Network programming before? Its pretty straight forward in C. And what you want can be implemented in a few hours. I used this manual below to finish my assignments back when i was a student.

http://shoe.bocks.com/net/

Just read this and you are good to go. Its really not very hard.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm looking for a cross platform solution.

Comment: @Robin: I still suggest you read a well-written non-portable solution to get familiar with network programming. Network sockets have nearly identical interfaces on different platforms, allowing you to port **clients** easily. Scalable network server architectures, however, vary **a lot** from one platform to the other.

Comment: What Andre says, they are almost the same. Porting it to various platforms it pain free at this level. I don't know exactly what you want to develop, but if you don't mind looking into java, its even easier there and its platform independent.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Answer (score 1):

As cross-platform and easy-to-use are both requirements I would recommend Qt. It's pretty easy, reliable and cross-platform.

http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/

It comes with lots of samples including 13 networking samples (take a look at the threaded server tutorial which I believe it's just what you're after).

Comment: Yes but its kinda bloat to use QT in this case imho and the licencing would be a problem if you are planing to use it commercially. LGPL trickier than one might think.

Comment: @zhengtonic - You can stick with LGPL. The commercial license is needed only if you plan to modify Qt's source and keep the changes closed source otherwise you can create you own commercial, closed-source application with Qt's LGPL license.  As far as the bloat goes I respectfully disagree, Qt is modularized so you should only need libqtcore and libqtnetwork. This is really a small price to pay for cross-platform. It's not like you'll be adding a virtual machine or anything like it, it will still be a native application